# Why does my fork insist I have changes from upstream and how do I fix this?

Tags: git, github

I created my fork https://github.com/jdx-john/ExchangeSharp in order to make changes, which I contributed upstream in a [PR](https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp/pull/600) and were accepted.

I fetched-upstream on my fork in GitHub, but now it tells me my fork's master 'branch is 4 commits ahead of jjxtra:master' and I must make a PR. However as far as I can see, there are no changes... "[showing 0 changed files](https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp/compare/master...jdx-john:master)"

I'm new to using forks (having used Git exclusively for feature branches on private projects) so I'm not sure if this is normal, or what I'm supposed to do about it as it seems messy. Did I do something wrong when making my PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

If you compare the commits from the upstream:

[image]

With your fork:

[image]

You could see that your fork has one extra (merge) commit.

### Multiple commits ahead

GitHub tells you you're multiple commits ahead because the merge commit points to other commits which aren't in the upstream

[image]

### The fix

The easiest way to fix is this is by deleting your fork and recreate it (but you could lose something!)

Or remove that commit from your master branch by resetting it to upstream/master

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git reset upstream/master --hard
git push --force-with-lease
```

if you don't have the upstream remote yet, add it as follows:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp.git
```

### Prevent this

- Don't work in your own master, but always create a new branch - guess you're doing that already.
- If you merge the upstream master to your master, use as fast forward merge. `git merge upstream/master --ff-only` - or a reset `git reset upstream/master --hard`

Answer (score 1):

Your fork is ahead the mergecommits of upstream back to your master. Maybe they also "signed off"/cherry-picked / recommitted/squashed your work so it got another commit ID.

As your branch does not have newer content (empty diff, just mergecommits) you can forcepush to upstream/master-HEAD to have it clean again.

This is not intended, you probably messed something up. It shouldn't happen if you make your proposed changes in a feature branch only, and only ff-merge upstream/master to fork/master