# GitHub: How to fix forked repo that is ahead and permission denied

Tags: git, github, permissions

I'm new to contributing to open-source projects. I previously forked a project and made some changes that I pull requested which they accepted. I plan on contributing further but I found that my forked repo is ahead and so I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72477056/git-fork-always-commits-ahead-i-dont-want/72480346#72480346) from another SO answer but got a permission denied error.

My steps are as follows:

1. git clone (my forked URL)
2. git remote add index (original project URL)
3. git fetch index
4. git push --force index origin
5. -> Asks to login to GitHub, inputs my GitHub account
6. `remote: Permission to <the original project> denied to <me>.`
7. `fatal: unable to access <the original project>: The requested URL returned error: 403`

I'm too fearful to go ahead since it may accidentally wreak havoc on the main project repo.

Comment: your problem is with your credentials, try to clone using ssh you will be able to push once you will succeed to clone

Comment: @Ôrel I already used ssh to clone my fork repo.

Comment: Found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074602/why-does-my-fork-insist-i-have-changes-from-upstream-and-how-do-i-fix-this).

Basically, I made the mistake of working on my own master and therefore need to start over by making another fork and working on another branch instead

Comment: `git push --force index ...` indicates to push to the "index" remote (if I'm correct : the upstream repo on which you don't have access). You should push to origin. Since it looks like you want to update your `master` branch : `git push origin index/master:master`

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks for the answer! Going to try it next time. Regarding the naming of "index", I found a tutorial that says the original source should be named "upstream". Sorry for the weird naming lol.